# Testing php mail() locally

Tags: php, apache, email, local

This question seems to my mind to be fundamentally different to the suggested duplicate. My requirements are very specific. If someone can tell me what I need to do to make this question acceptable, please do. I've tried three times now.

I want to use the php mail() function on a completely isolated machine running apache.

I want the contents of the email to be logged in a local text file.

Ideally I'd like a solution that works on both Windows7 and Ubuntu 14.04

I do not want to install any software other than apache and php unless absolutely necessary. I don't know if sendmail is part of apache, or if I need to install it separately.

I have tried this in php.ini and restarted apache:

`sendmail_path = 'cat > /home/****/Desktop/*****/dev/*******/email/mail.txt'`

to no avail. If only life were that simple.

Comment: Sendmail is a separate package and certainly not part of Apache.

Comment: this question requires several posts

Comment: I don't have the background knowledge to know how to split it meaningfully and still get the information I need.